# Can an Angular 4 component be a node module (so I can publish to npm)?

Tags: angular, npm, components

I'm working in an Angular 4 project (using angular-cli) and I made this component for autocomplete of html inputs, and it works, but then I thought "hey, maybe I can create a node project and publish to npm so I can use it anywhere".

This threw an error saying something related to my component not being in the compiling routes, that I should add it to tsconfig.json, and this makes sense for me, the nodes modules don't seem to contain any .ts files, just .js

My question is: is it posible to make an angular component usable on the npm registry? (without having to add it manually on tsconfig.ts).

here's a repo with a "default" angular cli project plus this component:
https://bitbucket.org/tavuntu/test-ng4-suggest

(note how I tried to convert it to a node module by adding package.json, index.js, etc.)

Here's the error I'm talking about:

```
import { Ng4SuggestComponent } from '.ERROR in ./node_modules/ng4-suggest/ng4-suggest.component.ts
Module build failed: Error: /home/g/Escritorio/test-repo-downloaded/node_modules/ng4-suggest/ng4-suggest.component.ts is not part of the compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/home/g/Escritorio/test-repo-downloaded/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:643:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/home/g/Escritorio/test-repo-downloaded/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
 @ ./node_modules/ng4-suggest/index.js 1:0-65
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
/ng4-suggest.component.ts';

exports.Ng4SuggestComponent = Ng4SuggestComponent;
```

Comment: There's a lot of steps involved in creating a reusable angular module. I've created a simple template which you can use to publish to NPM (you just have to add some components, and export them from public_api.ts): https://github.com/angular-patterns/ng-module-template

Comment: thanks, I'm going to try that out!

Comment: Let me know if you have questions